# Add rows per page to custom pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I'm trying to add rows per page as a select option here. I'm able to get the total and current page but I would like to add the option to increase rows per page to 20 or 30. I tried to use MUI's paginaton component but my project's theme clashes with it so I guess I should build a custom pagination....?

[image]

I'm getting the data from Redux and mapping it out like this.

```js
const { customers, isError, message, meta } = useSelector(
    (store) => store.customer
  );

  const pageNum = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= meta.lastPage; i++) {
    pageNum.push(i)
  }
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const onChange = (e) => {setPage(e.target.value);};

<Table variant="simple" color={textColor}>
            <Thead>
              <Tr my=".8rem" pl="0px" color="gray.400">
                {captions.map((caption, idx) => {
                  return (
                    <Th color="black" key={idx} ps={idx === 0 ? "6px" : "24px"}>
                      {caption}
                    </Th>
                  );
                })}
              </Tr>
            </Thead>
            <Tbody>
              {customers
                .filter((customers) => {
                  return search.toLowerCase() === ""
                    ? customers
                    : customers.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
                    customers.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(search);
                })
                .map((customers) => {
                  return (
                    <CustomersTable
                      key={customers.uid}
                      name={`${customers.first_name} ${customers.last_name}`}
                      logo={customers.logo}
                      id={customers.uid}
                      exchange={customers.exchange}
                      createdAt={moment(customers.createdAt).format("LLL")}
                    />
                  );
                })}
            </Tbody>
          </Table>
        </SkeletonText>
      </CardBody>
      <Flex justifyContent='space-between' alignItems='center' mt='20px'>
        <Text>Showing 1 to {meta.perPage} of {meta.total} Records</Text>
        <Text>page: {meta.currentPage}</Text>
        <Select w='70px' onChange={onChange} value={page} name='page'>
          {pageNum.map(a => <option>{a}</option>)}
        </Select>
      </Flex>
    </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need pass the perPage paramater to the BE side instead of the BE side is hardcode 10. Please connect with BE dev to solve it

Comment: Yeah thought as much.